# The set A is in a normed vector space W. $S=\bar A \cap \bar {A^c}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

The set A is in a normed vector space W. $S=\bar A \cap \bar {A^c}$ (S is the intersection of the closure of A and the closure of $A^c$). Is there a set A in W=R for which S=the set of rational numbers?

Answer (score 0):

No, $S$ is intersection of two closed set thus it is close, thus if $S=\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{R}=\bar{S}=S=\mathbb{Q}$ contradiction.